# mkdir does not Create folder if variable is used

Tags: php

I am having a problem with `mkdir` function.. If I execute code:

```
mkdir("../crafting/uploads/newfolder", 0777, true);
```

Works fine..But once I do this:

```
mkdir("../crafting/uploads/".$response['name'], 0777, true);
```

> It shows an error: File exists

**why is that?**

More code for the reference:

```
$email = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$response['name'] = $email ;
```

Both values `$email` or  `$response['name']` wont work

**SOLUTION:**

Ok, I got it working, it was just an error in my android file as I was fetching the wrong data from the database or something.

The code was like

```
String id = user.get("uid");
entity.addPart("name", new FileBody(id));
```

so the problem was that I used **FileBody(uid)** instead of just **id**

Comment: What do you have in $response['name']?

Comment: its just a name of an user, like tom or joe

Comment: This comment might apply to your situation http://php.net/manual/ro/function.mkdir.php#99810

Comment: Did you try print_r  $response before the mkdir function or use file name like a new variable ? for example: $newFolder = "../crafting/uploads/".$response['name']; mkdir($newFolder,...

Comment: Whats the Output of `echo "../crafting/uploads/ ". $response['name'];`? Put it directly above mkdir

Comment: Just a sec, i will try your suggestion and i will try to create simple variable and use it

Comment: Right..if i create a variable like $new = "newfolder"; and then do like `mkdir("../crafting/uploads/".$new, 0777, true);` it works fine again..

Answer (score -1):

First off, be sure $response is defined, if not, then assign it to an empty string like this:

```
$response_name=isset($response['name']) ? $response['name'] : "";
```

Then you can create your dir like this:

```
$your_loc="../crafting/uploads/".$response_name;

if(!is_dir($your_loc) && isset($response_name)){
  mkdir($your_loc,0777,true );
  echo "done";
}
```